# Objective-C: blocks and ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created utility class for UIAlerts. I am using blocks

My code, that user should create, looks like this:

```
MyAlertMessage * a = [[MyAlertMessage alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello" WithMessage:@"World"];

[a addButton:BUTTON_OK WithTitle:@"OK" WithAction:^(void *action) {
        NSLog(@"Button OK at index 0 click");
}];

[a addButton:BUTTON_CANCEL WithTitle:@"Cancel" WithAction:^(void *action) {
        NSLog(@"Button Cancel at index 1 click");
}];

[a show]
```

Full class can be seen here: https://github.com/MartinPerry/UIAlert

Now, If I do this, after [a show] ARC destroys my class, so blocks are no longer working and gives me error. I have solved this by creating singleton class that holds reference to created MyAlertMessage (message ads and destroys itself from this manager). Is this the correct solution or it should be done better, without this singleton manager?

Manager and appropriate class can be found here: https://github.com/MartinPerry/UIAlert/blob/master/UIAlert/MyAlertMessage.m

Comment: Are you subclassing UIAlertView or UIAlertController? Or attempting to do both? UIAlertView has a delegate you could use to do this and UIAlertController supports blocks anyway.

Comment: Your message naming is not standard. See [Naming Basics: Typographic Conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281-1002931-BBCFHEAB)

Comment: @keithbhunter his code (on GitHub) has references to iOS 7 and I don't believe UIAlertController is supported on anything below iOS 8.0

Comment: he doesn't use UIAlerts anyway -- and a manager looks good to me

Comment: Don't expect your users to go download your project from git. Post the appropriate code in your question. What does the header of your MyAlertMessage look like? What is the scope of the code you posted?

Comment: This is probably a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

The example code you posted uses a local variable to create a MyAlertMessage object. Since it is a local variable, it goes out of scope as soon as execution leaves the current set of braces (method, if statement, whatever.)  As soon as that happens nobody has a strong reference to the object, so it gets deallocated.

Make the MyAlertMessage variable an instance variable and set it to nil when you are done with it.